# oracle-cdc checkpoint always is IN_PROGRESS

Tags: apache-flink

[image: checkpoint history]

in log

```
2023-08-18 15:32:39,761 INFO  io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource   [] -      Exporting data from table 'TESTDB.LMIS.JC_HWZD' (1 of 1 tables)
2023-08-18 15:32:39,761 INFO  io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource   [] -      For table 'TESTDB.LMIS.JC_HWZD' using select statement: 'SELECT * FROM "LMIS"."JC_HWZD" AS OF SCN 19030388250928'
2023-08-18 15:32:40,109 INFO  io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask                  [] - 2048 records sent during previous 00:00:05.732, last recorded offset: {snapshot=true, scn=19030388250928, snapshot_completed=false}
2023-08-18 15:32:40,110 INFO  com.ververica.cdc.debezium.internal.DebeziumChangeFetcher    [] - Database snapshot phase can't perform checkpoint, acquired Checkpoint lock.
```

but other oracle cdc task works, only this one has bug.